# Text selection with custom menucontroller

Tags: javascript, objective-c, uiwebview, uitextview, core-text

I want select text likes iBooks app and kindle app. Based on the user selection we will display the UImenuItems.

If it is new one means we will show in the menucontroller multiple highlight colors and notes options.

We load the html file.

In this html file have tables, images and videos available.

currently I'm doing in uiwebiew. But I'm facing following problem

1.Add javascript to render the file based on the device size.(which is working);

1. I want select text to highlight the text. Within the note i can able to select.
   consider I can able to select text with the paragraph. If my selection goes to beyond the para it will not work properly.
2. I want Javascript to event listener for text select drag taping process.

please any one advice me..

If it is any frameworks is available, pls give me that link.
Weather any Possibilities in the coretext and uitextview also advice me.